# SELECT within SELECT with TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table one is Channels and Table two is Datum. The Datum is a many to one to Channels. I would like to get the latest Value and Date Time from the Datum table while looping through each of the channels.

I have a SELECT statement that is working but I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP(1) NumericValue 
     FROM Datum 
     WHERE ChannelId = test.ChannelId 
     ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS NumericValue, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) [DateTime] 
     FROM Datum 
     WHERE ChannelId = test.ChannelId 
     ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS DataTime, 
    ChannelId, Diag, ChannelDescription 
FROM 
    Channel as test 
WHERE 
    InstrumentID = 3
```

I have tried

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Top(1) NumericValue, [DateTime] 
     FROM Datum 
     WHERE ChannelId = test.ChannelId 
     ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC), 
    ChannelId, Diag, ChannelDescription 
FROM 
    Channel as test 
WHERE 
    InstrumentID = 3
```

How ever it errors with

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MAX` built in function to get latest value and time of channel:

```
SELECT 
    Value, _DateTime, ChannelId
FROM 
    Channel [test] 
JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(NumericValue) Value, MAX(DateTime) _DateTime , ChannelId
     FROM Datum 
     GROUP BY ChannelId) A ON A.ChannelId = test.ChannelId
WHERE 
    InstrumentID = 3
```

Comment: I had to add a.ChannelId

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and retain the first record per channel group of records, each group ordered descending by date.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ChannelId ORDER BY d.DateTime DESC) AS rn
    FROM Datum d
    INNER JOIN Channel c
        ON d.ChannelId = c.ChannelId
    WHERE c.InstrumentID = 3
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```