# SQL to get the latest date time row for each type

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need help with a SQL query that is very much like [SELECT within SELECT with TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235877/select-within-select-with-top).
However I need the latest date and the value for that date time-stamp. When using

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP(1) NumericValue 
     FROM Datum 
     WHERE ChannelId = test.ChannelId 
     ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS NumericValue, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) [DateTime] 
     FROM Datum 
     WHERE ChannelId = test.ChannelId 
     ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS DataTime, 
    ChannelId, Diag, ChannelDescription 
FROM 
    Channel as test 
WHERE 
    InstrumentID = 3
```

This is giving me the top value in the numeric column not the latest value. It gives me the latest datetime but I need the value for that also.

Comment: Your order is descending, so if you want the last row from your current output you should order it by ascending. Replace DESC to ASC

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you just want the Max [DateTime], and its correspondence NumericValue

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    test.ChannelId, test.Diag, test.ChannelDescription, test.[DateTime], sub.MaxNumericValueForDateTime
FROM
    Channel test
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT MAX(NumericValue) AS MaxNumericValueForDateTime 
    FROM Channel 
    WHERE InstrumentID = 3 AND [DateTime]=test.DateTime
    ) sub
WHERE
    InstrumentID = 3
ORDER BY
    [DateTime] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ChannelId, a.Diag, a.ChannelDescription, a.NumericValue, a.DateTime
FROM Channel a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ChannelId, MAX(DateTime) Max_DateTime 
            FROM Channel
            GROUP BY ChannelId) b ON a.ChannelId = b.ChannelId AND a.DateTime = b.Max_DateTime
WHERE a.InstrumentID = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) rn
    FROM Datum
)
SELECT 
    t.NumericValue, t.[DateTime]
FROM 
    Channel AS test CROSS JOIN t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1 AND
    test.InstrumentId = 3;
```